# Convert .gif image to base64 to upload to server

Tags: java, android, gif

I'm trying to encode an animated gif to base64, so I can upload it to server. I am already doing it with static images, but if I try to do it with GIF, it simply does not work. I get the image from Intent image picker and put it inside an ImageView.

Here is the code I use to encode images to base64:

```java
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView) nextChild).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, baos);
byte[] imginbyte = baos.toByteArray();
value = Base64.encodeToString(imginbyte, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: can you try png compression to avoir data loss? bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); I am not sure this will fix the issue as png image is static. The best thing to do is to encode your original image to base64 instead of doing this on the bitmap object.

Comment: I mean, an animated gif file is made out of several images that are displayed one after the other. A Bitmap is only one image, not several.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
byte[] imginbyte = Base64.decodeBase64(bitmap.getImageBase64());
new FileOutputStream("image2.gif");
write(imginbyte);
close();
```